# Execute PHP artisan scripts inside function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Would like to know how can i execute the PHP Artisan script inside my controller of Laravel?
Tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
php /Users/sl/Dropbox/Development/ABC/artisan currency:update;
```

This is the error returned:

syntax error, unexpected 'currency' (T_STRING)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Artisan::call('currency:update');` should work as you expected. Also you can push arguments in array, `Artisan::call('currency:update',  array('argument' => 'foo', '--option' => 'bar'));`